# writing a text file in the terminal with touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

i have looked everywhere and im feeling hopeless

my file is this

```
 mkdir -p ~/Desktop/new_file && echo "hello\\world > ~/Desktop/new_file.txt
```

I've also tried

```
 hello\n world

 hello ; world
```

I'm trying to accomplish a return signal to my hello world output for a multi line sentence all from the terminal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The man page for `echo` shows the following:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

       -n     do not output the trailing newline

       -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

       If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
       
       \\     backslash
       
       \n     new line
```

Which means that if you want multi-line output, you would simply start with `echo -e` and would add in a `\n` for new line.

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/new_file && echo -e "hello\nworld" >> ~/Desktop/new_file/new_file.txt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: its a text file inside a directory with hello world inside the text file

Comment: @hellomoto Ah, OK.  In your example, you are not writing into the new folder.

Comment: @hellomoto Updated my answer for you.

Comment: thank you Terrance, so its better to use >> instead of >

Comment: @hellomoto >> and > will both create the file.  However, > will overwrite the file if anything is in it and you want to create a new one.  >> will append to the file if it already exists.  If it does not, it will create one.  Usually, I like to use >> if I am putting multiple lines in a file as to not accidentally overwrite all the lines that were just barely added.  If you did a loop file that kept reading lines, the only line you would see with > would be the very last time it looped through.  So, you can make the choice.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly you want to use:

```
echo "hello" > ~/Desktop/new_file.txt && echo "world" >> ~/Desktop/new_file.txt
```

Then to check the results use `cat ~/Desktop/new_file.txt` which shows:

```
hello
world
```

There's a shorter way of doing this but I'm kind of new to Linux myself.

Answer (score 5):

First, although your title mentions `touch`, the command you have actually used is `mkdir` so you have created a *directory* called `new_file`. You will not be able to write text to `new_file` as-is.

In fact there's no need to create the target file in a separate step: redirecting a command's standard output to a named file will create it automatically if it does not already exist. *You can remove the (empty)* `new_file` *directory using* `rmdir ~/Desktop/new_file`

---

For the reasons outlined here [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/65304) you might want to consider instead using

```
printf 'Hello\nworld\n' > ~/Desktop/new_file
```

or use a [here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)

```
cat > ~/Desktop/new_file
Hello
world
```

which allows you to enter multiline text directly, terminating the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when you're done.

In either case, you can replace `>` by `>>` if you want to append to, rather than overwrite the existing contents of, the file.